# PHP: How to convert multicolumn sql query result into array

Tags: php, mysql

I've got sql database table which looks like this:

| login | time_start |
| --- | --- |
| name1 | 17:30:00 |
| name2 | 18:15:00 |
| name3 | 16:30:00 |
| name2 | 17:30:00 |

And i want to convert it into array with hour as id associated with all logins coresponding to that hour:

```
Array ( 
[ 18:15:00 ] => Array ( [login] => name2 ) 
[ 17:30:00 ] => Array ( [login] => (name1, name3) ) 
[ 16:30:00 ] => Array ( [login] => name3 )
)
```

---

I tried something like this:

```
if ($result && $result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $aReturn[$row['time_start']] = array(
            'login' => $row['login']
        );
   }
}
```

---

but it returned only 3 rows with only one login:

```
Array ( 
[16:30:00] => Array ( [login] => name3 ) 
[17:30:00] => Array ( [login] => name1 ) 
[18:15:00] => Array ( [login] => name2 ) 
)
```

Comment: Fine, so somewhere in either the SQL of the PHP code you are going ot have to convert `Hours:Minutes:Seconds` into `HOURS` I dont see any attempt to do that

Comment: You overwrite an entry. You don't add it to the array but just replace it when you have more then one name for a login time. Check if the key already exist, if so, append otherwise assign (like u do now)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do it

```
if ($result && $result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $aReturn[substr($row['time_start'], 0, 2)]['login'][] = $row['login'];
    }
}
```

you could do this for clarity ...

```
if ($result && $result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         if (!isset($aReturn[$hour = substr($row['time_start'], 0, 2)])) {    
            $aReturn[$hour] = ['login'=>[]];
         }
         $aReturn[$hour]['login'][] = $row['login'];
    }
}
```

but it's not functionally necessary in php

Comment: I like the clarity though. This is not needed now but could be if you add other logic besides adding data.

Comment: I missed the bit about the hour, amended now

Answer (score 0):

```
//get the SQL to convert the time into the hour

$sql = 'SELECT HOUR(time_start) as hour, login';
$results = $con->query($sql);
$allRows = $result->fetch_all();

foreach ($allRows as $row) {
    $aReturn[ $row['hour'] ]['login'][] => $row['login'];
}
```

RESULT should be like

```
Array
(
    [17] => Array
        ( [login] => Array ( [0] => name1, [1] => name4 ) )

    [18] => Array
        ( [login] => Array( [0] => name2 )  )

    [16] => Array
        ( [login] => Array  ( [0] => name3 ) )

)
```

OR, if you didnt mean you wanted to reduce the Time to only the Hour then simply

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $aReturn[ $row['time_start'] ]['login'][] = $row['login'];
}
```

Note removed the IF as if there is nothing to do the wjile loop will do nothing which is the same result as with the IF there.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question and I think timestamps don't need to be converted.

Comment: @Wimanicesir Thats quite possible :)

Comment: Although I will point to this part of the question which does not seem ambiguiious at all ___And i want to convert it into array with hour as id___ Thats **Hour** and not **Time** @Wimanicesir

Comment: True, the question is not that clear. However why I suppose it should not be converted is by his/her excepted result.

Comment: Sorry, for not quite good description of my problem, but I wasn't thinking about that little difference in those two words especially because English is my second language.

Comment: @RiggsFolly, you have a lot of points and a lot of experience. I hope this isn't coming over as an insult because it's just a recommendation. Code is universal, the English language isn't. So I would advise you to always assume the expected result is the actually result they want. Just like OP now explained, he did not think about the difference of the two words **Time** and **Hours**. Bottom line, don't think people are lazy but think people are bad at explaining a problem.

Comment: OK guys, i'm not really offended with those words so we can move on! Also i will be more specific!